# Websphere JMS with BUS

Tags: jms, websphere

Hi I am new to the Websphere JMS. It is bit different configuration i.e we need to create BUS first. I also seen that Connection factory has service bus reference and same service reference is given in Queue. I have following understanding till now

1. We have enterprise BUS to special needs. i.e BUS has control over the messages before MDB.
   We can filter,alter the message in the BUS.
2. What is relation between Connection factory and Queue.I just seen that Connection factory has same reference of BUS.
3. Why we refer the same BUS name in  Connection factory and Queue.

Please correct my understanding and help me in finding answers of above questions.

Answer (score 1):

SIBus is what holds the messaging engine(s) which contains destinations (point-to-point or publish/subscribe) and actually dispatch messages

In the JMS Part you got the Default JMS Provider which provides you JMS resources (Connection factories, Queues, Topics) which allows you to interact with the SIBus

In the SIBus you define a Destination on a messaging engine with some type (point-to-point or publish/subscribe)

A JMS Connection Factory creates connections to the messaging engine so you can send/receive messages, this is why you need to tell it which Bus you want it to create connections to

A JMS Queue referes to a point-to-point Destination in the SIBus.

Now for your questions:

The Bus itself is not intended to modify or filter messages
Filtering can be done by using a message selector in the MDB, when the MDB attach to the destination it will provide the message selector and the messaging engine will filter messages by it.
Regarding modification I am not sure

As I stated before, 
ConnectionFactory is what creates connections to the messaging engine while the Queue is an abstraction to the SIB Destination. This is why you need to tell each one which Bus it is interacting with.

Answer (score 1):

> Why we refer the same BUS name in Connection factory and Queue.

One reason is that the buses configured in the connection factory and the queue are not necessarily the same. That is the case in a topology with buses that are interconnected using SIBus links. In that case, you can connect to a messaging engine in one bus to send messages to a destination in another bus.